# exclude the first letter of a sentence from get_the_content() wordpress function

Tags: php, wordpress, substring

Anybody know how can I exclude only the first letter of a get_the_content() function in wordpress?

could be a snippet like that, but it doesn't work!

```
substr(strip_tags(get_the_content()), 1, get_the_content().length)
```

thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: Reference: [PHP string functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the third parameter, just write:

```
substr(strip_tags(get_the_content()), 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for something like this

```
$content = get_the_content();
$content = strip_tags($content);
$content = substr($content, 1, strlen($content));
```

You pretty much had it. Just needed to use the strlen() function to get the length of the string.